# Try / catch dose not catch on remote Ubuntu machine

Tags: c#, mariadb, blazor-server-side, background-service

I'm a little stumped as an exception isn't being caught in my app. However, this only happens on the rented remote machine. The machine runs Ubuntu 22.04 with the latest dotnet runtime environment.

Everything works as expected on my local Windows machine or on Docker. If a connection cannot be established there, you end up in the catch block. (Classic! Works on my machine)

The error occurs during `await connection.OpenAsync()` and the entire app is terminated. The following is output in the debug log in the output window:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.IOException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
The program '[77028] dotnet' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

For the database connection I use the connector from https://mysqlconnector.net/ in connection with Dapper.

What I don't understand at all is that the method is also used in another application and works without problems on the same machine.

**The method with strange behavior**

```
private async Task<MySqlConnection> GetDbConnectionAsync()
{
    Exception? connectionException = default;
    foreach (var connectionString in _connectionStrings)
    {
        var dbHost = connectionString.Split(';')
                                     .First(s => s.Contains("Server", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                                     .Split('=')[1];
        try
        {
            // Open database connection async
            var connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
            await connection.OpenAsync(); // <-- THIS CRASHING THE APPLICATION

            // Set connection session variables
            await SetSessionVars(connection);

            return connection;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            connectionException = ex;
            _log.LogError(ex,
                          $"[Data Access Layer]{Environment.NewLine}" +
                          $"Connection to database failed. Tried host: {dbHost}. Exception Message: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }

    _log.LogError($"[Data Access Layer]{Environment.NewLine}" +
                  "All configured database nodes are not reachable. Connection failure. Wait for 5 seconds and will retry.");
    await Task.Delay(5000);

    throw new
        InvalidOperationException("[Data Access Layer] All configured database nodes are not reachable. Connection failure. Wait for 5 seconds and will retry.",
                                  connectionException);
}
```

I am really thankful for all hints.

Comment: How do you know it's this method or this line?

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama Because the program is closed exactly at this point for every remote debug session.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, my mistake.
The machine already has a Blazor app running on the same Kestrel Port 5000.
For all those who are faced with such a problem, it can be very helpful to set under the Debug -> Windows -> Exception settings menu to interrupt execution for all exceptions.

[image]

Since a BackgroundService was already started and running in parallel, it was difficult to see that the Kestrel web server was not yet fully started in the background and that the IoException always occurred when the BackgroundService tried to connect to the database.

Don't forget to reset the exception settings so that the debugging experience isn't affected.